# MySQL to Redis and Redis to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, redis, bukkit

i want to optimize my game servers in Minecraft. I have 150k users in database, when daily on my servers join 15k users.

I have read about Redis, and i also read that Redis is faster than MySQL, i know that i can't give up from MySQL because my websites are using same database.

But what if i will load every 15 minutes all MySQL data to redis, then all my server plugins will work on this data, then after next 15 minutes redis will export that data to MySQL? I load same data to 4 servers and to 3 plugins on every server, so maybe loading it all to one redis server will be faster than send requests to MySQL from 4 servers * 3 Plugins?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi as much I can understand you have 4 mysql servers and 3 plugins.
As Redis is extremely fast no doubt but Redis use case is different than mysql. my advice is to load data in Redis which you'll use very frequently it'll be much faster than mysql, but to make it faster you have to design your keys intelligently so that Redis can search it faster. You can refresh keys and values after certain interval, defiantly your system's performance will improve.

Comment: I have 4 minecraft servers, and on every server are 3 minecraft server plugins. Every plugin use same mysql data from same server.

Comment: ok then just put data in redis from mysql and refresh after certain interval which you use more frequently instead of fetching it from mysql.

Comment: So its gonna be faster solution?

Comment: superfaster than before .. let me know if u face any problem

Answer (score 1):

Redis is an effective way to cache data from a MySQL database. Even though Redis has persistence options, many will still favor using a MySQL database for this task. As Redis operates in memory, it will be *much* faster than a MySQL database which (for the most part) does *not* operate in memory. Often, people will favor storing cache data with HashMaps, but since you have 3 servers, Redis would be a much better option. This way, you wouldn't have to create 3 near identical caches for each server.